# Image not showing on other systems when added using template URL WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to insert an image in WordPress Post and I want to give a dynamic URL so that if host changes than it will automatically change. Here is my code:

```
<div class="hmbox-right">
 <h1>Quality</h1>
  <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo.jpg">
  <p>Welcome to Turn Tekniks India, TUV ISO 2001 company, Manufacturer of Compasses (Drawing Instrument, Pencil Sharpeners and Crayon Holder.</p>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class="hmbox-right">
<h1>Quality</h1>
<img src="<?php get_template_directory(); ?>images/logo.png" alt="logo"
<p>Welcome to Turn Tekniks India, TUV ISO 2001 company, Manufacturer of Compasses (Drawing Instrument, Pencil Sharpeners and Crayon Holder.</p>   
</div>
```

This should work!

Comment: @user2999141 can you tell me what's happening?

Comment: @user2999141 Are you adding this code in the dashboard? And is it for a single post or would you like it to show in all posts? The code I supplied will only work if added to the php file directly?

Comment: @user2999141 yes it wouldn't because php can't be added using the dashboard. I'll try and work out another way for you!